# How to animate (resize) a Linear layout loaded into listview on item click in android

Tags: android, listview, animation

Hi i need to animate (resize height and width) a linear layout added into a Listview through adapter in android.

Comment: Where is the problem? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure as to what you want to do here. If im correct what your looking for is an expanded listview. You can achieve this using the following library it takes two layouts one for the listview item and the second the layout which needs to be expanded when the listview item is clicked

https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView